# Losing setTimeout value after I switch tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several columns of logos and I want to run a function that animates the logos on each column but not at the same time, I want to have a delay between the time the function runs for each column. Here is my code:

```
var startRotation = function() {
  $( ".ticker" ).each( function( index, element ){
    myInterval = setTimeout(function() { 
      otherInterval = setInterval(function(){ 
        slideImageUp(element); //runs function to animate
      }, 3000);
    }, 1000 * index); 
  });
};
```

The problem is setTimeout resets after I switch tabs on the browser and eventually the columns all animate at the same time. I've also tried pretty much every solution I found here and can't seem to figure out a way to make it work. I've been working on it for a while and I think the solution might be simple but I just can't see it. Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/dae0L0qu/3/

Comment: Nice work posting a working jsfiddle +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it the other way. Each 3 seconds, set timeouts for all the logos at the appropriate times.

```
var startRotation = function() {
  otherInterval = setInterval(function(){ 
      $( ".ticker" ).each( function( index, element ){
        myInterval = setTimeout(function() { 
          slideImageUp(element); //runs function to animate
        }, 1000 * index); 
      });
  }, 3000);
};
```

Comment: Wow, this simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The browser optimises for battery life and will "merge" your setTimeouts after you switch away. I suspect (but can't 100% confirm) it is what's happening here.

To resolve this, you will want to use CSS animations and/or transitions, which have better timing.

You'll need to rewrite your `slideImageUp` function to be using CSS, bind it to a class (eg `slide-up`) and then add the class to the elements.

With the power, performance, and hardware acceleration of CSS animations and transitions, you should almost never write these code in JS.

For more info, see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: Honestly, it was taking me a while to come up with the concept in CSS so I switched to jQuery because I knew I'd be able to get it done super fast, but then I got stuck with the setTimeout problem. I definitely took the easy route this time. Thanks for the advice though.